# Angular module dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

is possible I start my angular module without some dependency?

it's my angular.module

```js
angular.module("app", [
'ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ngMaterial',
'ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'NgSwitchery',
'ngCkeditor', 'angularFileUpload',
]);
```

I would like not use, they're required on 1st. loading.
'NgSwitchery', 'ngCkeditor', 'angularFileUpload'

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you could use condition to pass dependency.

```
var dependencyArray = ['dep1', 'dep2'];
if (someCondition) {
    dependencyArray = ['dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3', 'dep4'];
}

  angular.module('app',dependencyArray);
```

You might need requireJS if you're trying to load them at different times.